# Delphi IDE - MainForm shrinks when I click on any control

Tags: delphi, ide, shrink

Delphi 2010, Windows 8.1 64 bit.
I am having an oddity occur.  When I am in the IDE, I have my form displayed.  Every time I click on a control in the form, the form's height and width shrinks.  There is NOT empty space at the bottom of the form; controls (both visible and non-visible) are being hidden. It happens on multiple projects.  Has anyone seen this before?  This is a new install (about 2 weeks ago).  The only non-standard functionality I have is that I have both GExperts 1.3.6 installed, as well as CnPack IDE Wizards 1.0.2.666.

I do NOT get this behavior when running the application.

I have tried turning on 'Lock Controls' and this made no difference.

Comment: CNPack adds extra toolbars around the form's border for Tab Order Wizard, Caption Editor etc. Maybe this is reacting with Windows 8 and causing this odd effect?

Comment: Uninstall all that extra guff and see what happens.